# Turing machine to replace consecutive 1's with 0's

Tags: logic, computability, turing-machines, finite-state-machine

The task at hand is to construct a set of instructions for a Turing machine that changes consecutive (i.e. at substrings of at least two) 1's into 0's, leaving everything else on the tape untouched in five or fewer states, halting at standard position. The machine is moving left to right, and the only characters on the tape are 0's and 1's. I was wondering how to go about this -- I was able to come up with a set of instructions in five states that performs the task at hand but either halts at the first blank to the right of the tape or the first blank to the left of the tape but not proceed beyond that. Any suggestions would be very helpful!

For clarity, here are some examples of what the machine is supposed to do:

1) 1010 --> 1010

2) 1100 --> 0000

3) 001101 --> 000001

Comment: What does "halting at standard position" mean in your context? Do you need to count a halting state?

Comment: I suggest you that every time you find a 1, the TM changes the state to "I've seen a 1". If then, it sees another 1, then go backwards and start replacing until you find a 0, coming back to the state where you search for the first 1.

Comment: @HenningMakholm for us, it means that the machine should end positioned on the leftmost character when finished, and yes, I think the halting state counts (although wouldn't omitting that instruction give the same effect without the addition of a further state?).

Comment: Is there a limit to the number of $0$'s that are between the $1$'s?  Because if not, you'll never know if there are more $1$'s ...

Comment: @Bram28 the string is finite, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @4313 but the tape is not ... so is there maybe a special symbol after all the 1's and 0's that signals the end of the bit string?

Comment: @Bram28 oh, I see what you're asking now! Yes, a blank character denotes the end of the string. Something like an underscore.

Comment: @4313 Ah, ok, that makes sense ... are you still looking for some help with this problem? Javi's suggestion is pretty good ...

Comment: @Bram28 yes, I would still love some pointers -- the question I have about Javi's suggestion is wouldn't something like 01110 turn into just 00010 (and not 00000) if I turned back and started replacing after the first 1 I saw? The second pass would only reveal a single 1, not consecutive 1's.

Comment: @4313 No, that wouldn't happen: After seeing the second $1$, you go back to the beginning, but you make sure are now in a different state from the beginning, i.e. a state that represents that you have seen consecutive ones and so are now going to replace them all with zeroes. And so in that state you just keep replacing every one with a zero until you see a zero.

Comment: @4313 I just added the beginning of the machine ... see if you can complete the rest yourself. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a start based on Javi's suggestion:

[image]

State $0$ is the 'top' of the loop: here, you just skip all $0$'s until you see a $1$. Then when you see a $1$, leave that $1$ alone, but go to a new state (state $1$) that represents "I have seen a $1$"

In state $1$, you see if there is another $1$ rioght next to the $1$ you just saw. If not, go back to state $0$. But if you do see a $1$, then it's time to replace the $1$ with $0$, but to do this, leave that second $1$ alone and move back to the first $1$ .. but go to a new state (state $2$) that says "time to replace the $1$'s with $0$'s!

OK, so in state $2$ you keep replacing all $1$'s with $0$'s until you are done with that string of consecutive $1$'s ... and then you return to state $0$.

Now, what you need to do is extend/modify this machine to account for the fact that at some point you will get to the end of the $0$'s and $1$'s  ... at which point you of course just need to return to the leftmost $0$ or $1$.